# Concatenate a macro parameter with text

Tags: c++, macros

I am currently working on porting some code from Visual Studio to Mingw GCC. The code builds and runs fine in visual studio but has some issues on Mingw GCC. One of the issue I am having is with Macro Expansion. I have simplified this example here.

```
#define DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(ClassType) \
        typedef LG_Wrapper::##ClassType##<LG_Wrapper::TA>               ClassType; \
        typedef LG_Wrapper::##ClassType##<LG_Wrapper::TB>           ClassType##TPR; \
        typedef LG_Wrapper::##ClassType##<LG_Wrapper::TC>   ClassType##DBN; \
```

Now when I attempt to build this I get the error(s)

```
 error: pasting "::" and "GraphicsDevice" does not give a valid preprocessing token
   typedef LG_Wrapper::##ClassType##<LG_Wrapper::TA>    ClassType; \
                     ^
 note: in expansion of macro 'DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES'
 DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(GraphicsDevice);
 ^
 error: pasting "GraphicsDevice" and "<" does not give a valid preprocessing token
 DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(GraphicsDevice);
```

Any suggestions on why I get this issue in mingw GCC and not in Visual Studio and how would i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the first two `##` from each line of the `DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES` macro or create a new version without them. They're completely unnecessary, and the error GCC is giving is allowed by the Standard C++, if not actually required. The result of using the ## preprocessing operator must be a valid preprocessing token and `::GraphicsDevice` isn't a valid preprocessing token.

You want something like this:

```
#define CONFORMING_DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(ClassType)                    \
        typedef LG_Wrapper::ClassType<LG_Wrapper::TA> ClassType;      \
        typedef LG_Wrapper::ClassType<LG_Wrapper::TB> ClassType##TPR; \
        typedef LG_Wrapper::ClassType<LG_Wrapper::TC> ClassType##DBN;
```

Comment: If i remove the first two `##` wont the parameter substitution stop ? For instance in the example you posted. Using  `CONFORMING_DECLARE_LEGACY_TYPES(foo)` for the first case will yield `LG_Wrapper::ClassType<LG_Wrapper::TA> ClassType;` while the second case will yield `LG_Wrapper::foo<LG_Wrapper::TA> ClassType;` ? And i want the second case

Comment: No, why would it?  And you don't want the second case, you want `LG_Wrapper::foo<LG_Wrapper::TA> foo`. All instances of the preprocessor token `ClassType` will be replaced just like in any macro substitution.

Comment: You are correct. I tried this out and apparently the parameter does get substituted. I wonder why we need `##` then ?

Comment: You need the ## to create a new preprocessor token out of two tokens. If the macro had `typedef ... ClassTypeTPR` then ClassType wouldn't get substituted because ClasTypeTPR is a different token with a different name. If it instead had `typedef ... ClassType TPR` the substitution would happen, but itwouldn't work because you'd get `typedef ... foo TPR`. By using `ClassType##TPR` then ClassType gets replaced by foo and then the two tokens, `foo` and `TPR` get pasted together to form one token `fooTPR`.